# Good queue system - or, how to place a job in resque from another language

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, queue, message-queue, resque

I'm developing a new application which is developed in a few different languages. Some Ruby, some Python, some Erlang and some C.

I'm using Ruby on Rails for the webpage, and since I have a lot of background jobs I'm using resque to queue these jobs. However, I would like to be able to place jobas in the resque queue from other processes than just my Rails project. Is it possible to place a job in resque from a C program?

Or, is there another queue-system which is less language specific?

I know I could just setup a small internal webapp as interface for resque, but that seems quite cumbersome for just placing jobs in a queue

Answer (score 0):

It should be possible. Resque is just writing/reading JSON from the Redis server for its jobs. The [Sidekiq project](http://github.com/mperham/sidekiq), for example, is Resque-compatible. Perhaps you can study how they implemented that compatibility.